# Browse a website on localhost from remote device

Tags: linux, apache, localhost, vhosts

I am on ubuntu 12.04. Hosts file:

```
127.0.1.1 site.to.browse
```

Vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.to.browse
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/website/root"
    <Directory /path/to/website/root>
        AllowOverride All
        Options All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

On my android device that is connected to the same WIFI as the host I try to access this site with

```
192.168.178.57/site.to.browse
```

but I get a 404. When I browse just 192.168.178.57/ I get my default IT WORKS page.

Any ideas how to access the specified website?

Comment: can you put the output of `ls -la /path/to/website/root` please?

Comment: You are missing basic concept of apache here, first of all don't run apache on loopback IP.

Comment: It would aid our attempt to answer your question if you gave us a few comments on the already posted solutions. Is any of these what you are looking for? Did we understand your question correctly?

Comment: @Scolytus sorry had no time to check the solutions. BTW if I access 192.168.178.57/phpmyadmin on my phone it works

Comment: @artworkadシ I guess you installed phpmyadmin as an Ubuntu package. This will create a link `/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf -> /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`. This file does the same as my answer: it creates an alias on the default host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
192.168.178.57 site.to.browse
```

to the hosts file on your android phone, so that it knows that `http://site.to.browse/` refers to your server at `192.168.178.57`.

---

If you want to access your vhost using `http://192.168.178.57/site.to.browse` instead, you'll need to do a local URL rewrite *on the default vhost* that redirects the page request to the desired vhost. So, in the Apache configuration for the default vhost, add

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/*site\.to\.browse/*(.*)$ http://site.to.browse/$1 [PT,L]
```

Unfortunately, this causes a discrepancy between the URL the client uses (say, `http://192.168.178.57/site.to.browse/some/page.html`) and the one that the server actually serves (`http://site.to.browse/some/page.html`). In particular, absolute paths (`/some/page.html`) will not be redirected correctly.

You can avoid this by *reverse-proxying* the internal vhost from the default vhost, using e.g. mod_proxy_html and/or mod_substitute to adjust URLs and paths in the content.

A much more practical approach, for testing, is to put everything interesting in your vhost inside a top folder, so that absolute URLs will only differ by the hostname part. For this, you need

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/*site\.to\.browse/*(.*)$ http://site.to.browse/site.to.browse/$1 [PT,L]
```

in the Apache configuration for the default vhost, and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/*site\.to\.browse$ /site.to.browse/ [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/*site\.to\.browse/
RewriteRule ^/*(.*)$ /site.to.browse/$1 [R,L]
```

in the vhost configuration; this latter part will redirect any `http://site.to.browse/foo` to `http://site.to.browse/site.to.browse/foo`, including `http://site.to.browse/` to `http://site.to.browse/site.to.browse/`.

Obviously, you don't need to use `site.to.browse` as the folder name; you could just use e.g. `mysite`. The configuration would then be

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/*mysite/*(.*)$ http://site.to.browse/mysite/$1 [PT,L]
```

on the default vhost, and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/*mysite$ /mysite/ [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/*mysite/
RewriteRule ^/*(.*)$ /mysite/$1 [R,L]
```

in the site.to.browse vhost. The latter will redirect anything not under the mysite folder to under the mysite folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to access the site by `http://192.168.178.57/site.to.browse/`
then I would simply add the following line to your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` inside the **default** `VirtualHost`:

```
Alias /site.to.browse /path/to/website/root

<Directory /path/to/website/root>
    AllowOverride All
    Options All
</Directory>
```

Explanation: The VHost configuration you provided in your question will have no effect in this case.

The android client will send a request to the host identified by the IP Address, not the DNS-Name `site.to.browse`. Thus `HTTP_HOST` will be `192.168.178.57`. So Apache won't take you vhost configuration since you don't request something from the host `site.to.browse`. Instead, apache's default config will be used which lives in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`.

As an alternative you could just replace the default **It Works** page by your own page, thus making the page available as `http://192.168.178.57`.

Of course you have to ensure that apache also binds to the machine's public IP. Since you get the **It works** page I take that as granted.

Answer (score 0):

You need edit your vhost or .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^site.to.browse$    index.php    [NC,L]
```